# Approve multiple infopath forms at the same time in few clicks

Tags: workflow, infopath, designer-workflow

I have a system where there 45-50 infopath forms filled every month. it becomes tedious to open each and every form and approve it. Is there any way or code to approve multiple forms by selecting them in one go.

Please suggest an approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

What version and license of SharePoint??? (!) What have you tried?

There is a Codeplex project to approve multiple items: http://approvemultipleitems.codeplex.com/

You can also approve multiple items if the publishing feature is enabled. You need to go Site Actions > Site Settings > Content and Structure (in SharePoint 2010 Enterprise) as described [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/13edc595-13c9-4393-81cf-72d96fe919cb/approve-multiple-documents)

Comment: I am working on sharepoint 2013 version.

Comment: Thanks a lot first of all. I saw the codeplex link but it is designed on Task List. Will it work on Form Library.